# Xerces-c assertion error

Tags: c++, xml, xerces, xerces-c

I have downloaded and built Xerces-c on linux:

```
Linux xxxx 2.6.24.7-server-3mnb #1 SMP Wed Sep 9 16:34:18 EDT 2009 x86_64 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU            3065  @ 2.33GHz GNU/Linux
```

Created the simple program:

```
#include <xercesc/sax2/XMLReaderFactory.hpp>
#include <xercesc/sax2/SAX2XMLReader.hpp>
#include <xercesc/sax2/DefaultHandler.hpp>
#include <xercesc/util/XMLUni.hpp>
//#include <xercesc/validators/common/Grammar.hpp>

   XERCES_CPP_NAMESPACE_USE;

int main(int argC, char *argv[])
{
    //  DefaultHandler handler;
    SAX2XMLReader *parser = XMLReaderFactory::createXMLReader();
    delete parser;
    return 0;
}
```

compiled it:

```
g++ -lcurl -o xtest test.cpp /usr/local/lib/libxerces-c.a
```

successful compile, run it and this is what I get:

```
 ./xtest
xtest: xercesc/util/XMemory.cpp:63: static void* xercesc_3_1::XMemory::operator new(size_t, xercesc_3_1::MemoryManager*): Assertion `manager != 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Anyone have similar experience/successfully built and used this library... how? It's becoming a real pain and apparently it's the only thing for linux that properly validates an XML document against multiple schemas with namespace support (or is it??)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to call [XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classXMLPlatformUtils.html#_details) before using any xerces functionality.

> Initialization must be called first in any client code.

Also, don't forget [XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classXMLPlatformUtils.html#dc0dcc57907126e06a2f5e376b392794)() once you're done with xerces i.e. at the end of the program.

> The termination call is currently optional, to aid those dynamically loading the parser to clean up before exit, or to avoid spurious reports from leak detectors.

AFAIR failing to init xerces results in the error you listed.